# Persistance in Java

Tags: java, android, persistent

How do I use persistance in Java?

Comment: You can use onSaveInstance() to persist data between runs and SharedPreferences to persist data more permanently.

Comment: Shared Preferences are the way to go for the persistence level you are asking for. Can you post what you tried with them?

Comment: @AlexGittemeier I was able make the app work with shared preference when my options were radio buttons, but I found no sources anywhere on how to be able to work in the menu format that I'm employing here, any help on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you store `item.getItemId()` inside `onOptionsItemSelected` in your SharedPreferences, then move the `switch` block to a new function so that in your `onCreate` you can call that new function to restore the selection:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefName", 0);
    int thicknessId = prefs.getInt("thicknessFieldName", 1); // Replace 1 with first-load state
    switchScribbleView(thicknessId);

    int colorId = prefs.getInt("colorFieldName", 4); // Replace 4 with first-load state
    switchScribbleView(colorId);

    //... rest of code
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int menuId = item.getItemId();

    //Get old values so they persist
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefName", 0);
    int thicknessId = prefs.getInt("thicknessFieldName", 0);
    int colorId = prefs.getInt("colorFieldName", 0);

    if (menuId <= 2) // Control Thick and Thin
        thicknessId = menuId;
    else if (menuId >= 4) // Control Color
        colorId = menuId;

    Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("prefName", 0).edit();
    editor.putInt("thicknessFieldName", thicknessId);
    editor.putInt("colorFieldName", colorId);
    editor.commit();

    switchScribbleView(item.getItemId();
    return true;
}

private void switchScribbleView(int menuId) {
    switch (menuId) {
        //... switch block here
    }
}
```

Comment: As an added bonus, this implementation will allow you to show the selected menu items with just 3-5 more lines.